# Is it possible to show gradients with react-svgmt?

Tags: reactjs, svg, hyperlink, gradient

I would like to use react-svgmt to manipulate SVG's. These SVG's can be uploaded from the users. My problem is, that if the SVG has a gradient these parts of the SVG are not shown.

Has anybody a solution for my problem to reactivate these links after the import of the SVG via react-svgmt?

With the developertools of my browser I was be able the see that the elements are in the code, but the grandients will be linked to the elements and these links are broken.

I have seen that other people has the same problem with gradients and created an issue on github, but the developer did not respond.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem.
react-svgmt add to elements like linearGradients "-{nr}" to its id-names. Then this `fill:url(#linear-gradient-2);` does not work anymore in the style-tags, because it must be `fill:url(#linear-gradient-2-{nr});`.

So the first SVGProxy after loading is `<SvgProxy selector="linearGradient" onElementSelected={handleGradients} ></ SvgProxy>`
an the function handleGradients looks like following and saves the {nr}
`const handleGradients = (gradients) => { if (typeof gradients.length !== 'undefined') { const output = gradients.map((g, i) => { nr = g.id.substring(g.id.lastIndexOf("-")+1); setNr(g.id.substring(g.id.lastIndexOf("-")+1)); if(g.href.baseVal.length > 0) { var base = g.href.baseVal; g.href.baseVal = base + '-' + nr; } return g; }); } else  { nr = gradients.id.substring(gradients.id.lastIndexOf("-")+1); setNr(gradients.id.substring(gradients.id.lastIndexOf("-")+1)); if(gradients.href.baseVal.length > 0) { var base = gradients.href.baseVal; gradients.href.baseVal = base + '-' + nr; } } };`

Then I had another SVGProxy
`<SvgProxy selector="defs > style" onElementSelected={handleStyleElem} ></ SvgProxy>`

with the following handlefunction which replaces all urls with the schema from above
`const handleStyleElem = (svgStyle) => { var styleStr = svgStyle.outerHTML; styleStr = styleStr.replaceAll(/url\(#((\w|-)*)\);/g, 'url(#$1-'+ nr +');'); svgStyle.outerHTML = styleStr; };`